# JS Filter array of objects by capital city first and then alphabetically

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of objects like:

```
[{"City":"Hamburg", ...}, {"City":"Berlin", ...}, {"City":"Berlin", ...}, {"City":"Stuttgart", ...},{"City":"Augsburg", ...}]
```

How can I order them alphabetically but have the capital city Berlin first like:

```
[{"City":"Berlin", ...}, {"City":"Berlin", ...}, {"City":"Augsburg", ...}, {"City":"Hamburg", ...}, {"City":"Stuttgart", ...}]
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any list of City which needs to be sorted in specific order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
let array = [
    {"City": "Hamburg"},
    {"City": "Berlin"},
    {"City": "Berlin"},
    {"City": "Stuttgart"},
    {"City": "Augsburg"}
];
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.City === "Berlin")
        return -1;
    if (b.City === "Berlin")
        return 1;
    if (a.City < b.City) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.City > b.City) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
console.log(array);
```